# Can I remove the second "is"?

Tags: punctuation, syntax, ellipsis

please consider that English is not my first language :D thanks

the sentence:

[...], however, as he is not only holding onto the rope but is tied to it just like his counterpart, the native, [...]

my problem:

can I just remove the second "is"? -> he is not only holding onto the rope but tied to it? both versions sound really awkward to me but I can`t think of any other way to express it right now

Comment: I prefer the cadence of the version with the second *is*.

Comment: Perhaps you can try rewriting in the following form: ;however, not only is he holding onto to the rope, but like his counterpart, is also tied to it.

Comment: As it is written, both versions are correct. I actually prefer the version *without* the second *is* (American English)

Comment: Now that's remarkable, as for me, removing the second *is* creates a syllepsis and a garden-path sentence. It's horrible at best.

Comment: I dislike dropping the second *is* because the two have different syntactic functions: the first is a progressive auxiliary and the second is a passive auxiliary. It's a "She left in a huff and a sedan chair" sort of thing.

Comment: thanks for replying, I guess I`m going to keep the second _is_ and leave it as it is

Comment: For parallelism, you would have either "not only is ... but is...." or else "is not only ... but ..."  Yours is a mixture of these two, so not precisely parallel.

Answer (score 1):

You can't remove the second "is" because "is holding" and "is tied" are two different types of verbs.  A compound verb can share an "is," but a compound verb must be made up of the same kind.

"Is holding" is a present progressive form, whereas "is tied" is [copula + participle].  The first verb is an active action verb and the second is a passive status.

Comment: I think saying "can't" here is too strong. I agree that it is better to retain the second is, both for this reason and for parallelism as indicated by  @GEdgar ina comment to teh question. But this sort of construction is used often enough, including by fluent speakers, that it cannot be labeled 'wrong. Moreover, if the second if is removed it does not seriously lead to any ambiguity, nor even to the kind of surprise that syllepsis  often generates, as in "The cook was a good cook as cooks go, and as cooks go she went" ("Reginald on Besetting Sins" Saki)

Comment: I agree with @DavidSiegel that "can't" is too strong. But I think it's fair to say many if not most native speakers ***wouldn't*** discard the second instance of ***is*** in the cited context. And regardless of whether or not they were aware of ***why*** they'd normally make that choice, I think the underlying reason is precisely as set out here.

Answer (score 0):

This is an example of the so called correlating conjunction **not only... but** in a sentence structure having two predicate phrases. The meaning which the conjunction is conveying here is emphasizing the additional predicate element *is tied to it* in the sentence. This makes the sentence keep the rules of the so called **parallel structure**. We must use an analogous grammatical form in the second predicate phrase. That is why it is impossible to redact *is* from the second phrase here, in formal writing at least.